# I can't find .env file Laravel on Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, file, cmd

I'm using Laravel for the first time. I have to run this command: "php artisan key:generate" but i get this:

```
 [ErrorException]
```

file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have no ".env" file or ".example.env".
What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to view `.env` and `.env.example` files? Some editors hide files that start with a dot. You use the `.env.example` to create your `.env` usually.

Comment: I was wrong to write, i wanted to write "php artisan key:generate"

Answer (score 1):

You can always generate .env file manually by running:

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

Must be Turns out the IDE will show certain types of .hidden files but not all

Comment: i have no .env.example file. "cp" comand doesn't exist in Windows. I'm not using any IDE.

Comment: On Windows use `copy` instead of `cp`. You can use this `.env.example` since you don't have one: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example.